# XML not well formed exception - on specific characters

Tags: android, xml

**Hi**
I am trying to make an arrow buttons with the characters:  "<" , ">"
For some reason it screams on : android:text="<"
If I change to "*" for example, it will get complied successfully
what should I change?

Comment: You have to escape some characters:
[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using &lt; for < and &gt; for > instead inside the double quotes.

```
android:text="&lt;"
```

or

```
android:text="&gt;"
```

Comment: can you write an example ?